# Falta 1 argumento posicional

Tags: python, flask

Me devuelve el error "producto() missing 1 required positional argument: 'data'" pero no logro comprender ya que desde mi HTML/flask le estoy pasando los dos argumentos pero sin solucion

Este es mi codigo en python

```
@bp.route("/catalogo/product/<name>", methods=["GET"])
def producto(name, data):
    db, c = get_db()
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM catalogo WHERE product_id = %s",(data,))
    todo = c.fetchone()

    return render_template(f"web/product/{name}", data=data, todo=todo)
```

Y este mi codigo de HTML/FLASK

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<section>
   <div class="content">
       <div class="flexcontent">

           {% set path = 'static/fotos/' %}
           {% for dato in datos %}
           <div class="image">
               <a href="{{ url_for('.producto', name=dato['product_html'], data=dato['product_id'] )}}"><img src="{{ path }}{{ dato['product_url'] }}" width=276px class="product-image"></a>
               <span>{{ dato['product_name'] }}</span>
               <span>${{ dato['product_price'] }}</span>
           </div>
           {% endfor %}
       </div>
   </div>
</section>
{% endblock %}
```

El name recibe bien su argumento por lo que data deberia recibir el product_id tambien de forma correcta

Comment: En Python, suele emplearse el argumento `self` en la primera posición. Entonces la declaración sería de esta forma: `def producto(self, name, data)`. `self` en Python equivale a `this` en otros lenguajes de programación.

Comment: @HéctorM. Lo de self es lo primero que pensé también al ver el título, pero viendo el código no aplica, ya que no se están usando clases aquí.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que en tu función manejadora para la ruta has declarado dos parámetros, pero la ruta en sí solo "declara" uno, pues tu ruta es `"/catalogo/product/<name>"`

Creo que tu problema se resuelve pasando ambos parámetros en la ruta:

```
@bp.route("/catalogo/product/<name>/<data>", methods=["GET"])
def producto(name, data):
    ...
```

aunque todo depende un poco de qué contengan exactamente "name" y "data" ya que si contienen barras o caracteres "especiales" podrían confundir al parser de flask que tiene que extraerlos de la url. Supongo no obstante que `url_for()` de jinja se ocupará de aplicarles "quote" para que esos caracteres especiales pasen a ser válidos.